# issue with android studio3.x : build project failed

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

excuse me, I am just starting learning android developing.

I have installed android studio 3.2, and create a new project. nothing edit, and got this.

[image: error]

I have googled a lot, and have tried:

1. unchecked `settings-->gradle-->offline work`
2. checked to enable embedded maven repository
3. added `maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }`
4. update AS to newest 3.2.1

It still not works..

build.gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    //maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.testapp.activitylifecycletest"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Very Thanks!

Comment: Try **Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: I have tried,but it is not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same case,you can check your proxy settings.
In your gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties file add proxy settings as follow

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
```